# How does MongoDB store data efficiently?

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql, bson

Could someone please help me understand how mongoDB efficiently stores and retrieves data.

In the docs it shows the following example.
To insert:

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
   // MongoDB adds the _id field with an ObjectId if _id is not present
  { item: "journal", qty: 25, status: "A",
   size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, tags: [ "blank", "red" ] },
  { item: "notebook", qty: 50, status: "A",
   size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, tags: [ "red", "blank" ] },
  { item: "paper", qty: 100, status: "D",
   size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, tags: [ "red", "blank", "plain" ] },
  { item: "planner", qty: 75, status: "D",
   size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, tags: [ "blank", "red" ] },
  { item: "postcard", qty: 45, status: "A",
   size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, tags: [ "blue" ] }
 ])
```

And to retrieve:

```
  db.inventory.find( { status: "D" } )
```

I know that it uses BSON in the internals. But could someone give me an idea of how this works (for the above example perhaps) and how key-value pairs can be efficiently stored and retrieved.

Thanks.

Comment: This is handled by the storage engine (likely WiredTiger. Less likely MMAPv1). These are keywords for googling.

Answer (score 0):

You can read these documents:

[What’s New in MongoDB 3.0 Part 3: Performance & Efficiency Gains, New Storage Architecture](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/whats-new-mongodb-30-part-3-performance-efficiency-gains-new-storage-architecture)

[MongoDB Docs WiredTiger Compression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression)

[WiredTiger Storage Engine FAQ](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#wiredtiger-storage-engine)

In Short: WiredTiger compresses the data when persisting it to disk